# OAuth PHP for Windows?

Tags: php, dll, oauth, xampp, pecl

I'm running XAMPP on windows and trying to install Oauth into PHP. I already tried running "pecl install oauth" but it gave me error. i don't have a compiler to compile the OAuth 1.10 into .dll, and really don't have the time to learn how to compile it.

the link for the pecl package is here: http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/1.1.0

**EDIT** after running 'pecl install oauth' the error i get is this:

> WARNING: php_bin C:\XAMPP\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php.exe,
>   but config variable php_suffix does not match.
>   ERROR: The DSP oauth.dsp does not exist.

thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem as well.

Comment: me too! There are similar posts like this..trying to find out how to get OAuth on php windows..but none have any definitive answers other than getting to compile urself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043453/pecl-oauth-1-2-2-for-windows

Answer (score 3):

This is usually do to incompatibility between the oAuth version and PHP.  You can get the latest oAuth library precompiled from the windows.php.net site:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/

Also don't forget to add the extension to your php.ini and restart Apache afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

[Install APC on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437737/install-apc-on-windows):

> PECL is used for downloading and
>   compiling extensions, but Windows
>   machines generally don't have what is
>   required to compile these, instead try
>   looking for and downloading a
>   pre-compiled .dll.