# PECL OAuth-1.2.2 for Windows

Tags: windows, oauth, pecl

I'm trying to get PECL OAuth to work on a Windows dev box (using WAMP). I found two dlls for older versions at [Pierre's site](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) but neither of them seem to work.

Adding the DLL to the relevant wamp\bin\php\php5.x.x\ext directory and then ticking the option in the PHP extensions flyout does not add anything OAuth related to the output of phpinfo() and if I try to instantiate an OAuth object I get a "Class 'OAuth' not found" error.

Is there anywhere (or any way) that I can get hold of working DLLs (ideally for the latest 1.2.2 version of OAuth, but any 1.0 or higher stable version will do). The maching in question is running 32bit Windows (Vista).

I hope somebody can help where Google has failed me so far...!

Thanks in advance,

Christian

Comment: I'm also stuck just like you..looks like time to ditch windows and move to unix/linux at least for getting php OAuth ext

Answer (score 0):

I'm just barely beginning to delve into this whole thing, so I'm not quite sure which way is up, but does this article on  [oAuth, Xampp, and Windows,](http://jonas-doebertin.de/2011/03/oauth-mit-xampp-unter-windows-nutzen/) scroll down for the English, do the trick?

Let me know as I'm eager to figure all this out too!

And/or would one be able to  [build it with windows?](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild)

Comment: link is broken.